# read -r is wrongly breaking the file fields

Tags: bash

I have file named fields ,which should contained 4 fields

Example filed from the file:

```
rhel-x86_64-server-7 string1_string2_string4 STRING5  STRING6 7 STRING6 64-bit 2016-06-13
```

in the beginning there was 3 fields in the file without the date filed  at the end  ,like this:

```
rhel-x86_64-server-7 string1_string2_string4 STRING5  STRING6 7 STRING6 64-bit
```

once I had the 3 fields file ,I have created a while read loop to read the lines one by one and give me  3 variables

```
while read -r  filed1  filed2 filed3 ;do
    echo "$filed1"
    echo "$filed2"
    echo "$filed3
```

So if I echo those fields I was getting:

```
rhel-x86_64-server-7
string1_string2_string4
TRING5  STRING6 7 STRING6 64-bit
```

but  when I added the forth filed to the file (the date filed)  and added the forth variable to the while loop , IE:

```
while read -r  filed1  filed2 filed3 filed4 ;do
```

when echoing , I am getting something like that:

```
rhel-x86_64-server-7
string1_string2_string4 
STRING5 
STRING6 7 STRING6 64-bit 2016-06-13
```

I am expecting to get the following lines:

```
rhel-x86_64-server-7
string1_string2_string4
STRING5 STRING6 7 STRING6 64-bit  
2016-06-13
```

Can you please suggest how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

> in the beginning there was 3 fields in the file without the date filed
>   at the end ,like this:
>
> ```
> rhel-x86_64-server-7 string1_string2_string4 STRING5  STRING6 7 STRING6 64-bit
> ```

It's not clear what 3 fields you're talking about. For your information Bash sees the fields like this:

1. rhel-x86_64-server-7
2. string1_string2_string4
3. STRING5
4. STRING6
5. 7
6. STRING6
7. 64-bit

And notice in `help read`:

> ```
> One line is read from the standard input, or from file descriptor FD if the
> -u option is supplied, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME,
> the second word to the second NAME, and so on, with leftover words assigned
> to the last NAME.  [...]
> ```

Especially the last part, *leftover words assigned to the last NAME*.
This is why `STRING5  STRING6 7 STRING6 64-bit` were all stored in the same variable, `filed3`, not because these are in one field, but because these are the leftovers.

If you want to chop off the last field delimited by a space, pattern substitution might help:

```
while read -r f1 f2 f3; do
    echo "$f1"
    echo "$f2"
    echo "${f3% *}"
    echo "${f3##* }"
```

`${f3% *}` is `f3` with everything chopped off after the last space.

`${f3##* }` is `f3` with everything chopped off until the last space.

Output for your example input:

> ```
> rhel-x86_64-server-7
> string1_string2_string4
> STRING5  STRING6 7 STRING6 64-bit
> 2016-06-13
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do would be to read the values into an array instead, then use substring expansion to gather the desired fields together.

```
read -r -a fields
field1=${fields[0]}
field2=${fields[1]}
field3=${fields[@]:2:${#fields[@]}-5}
field4=${fields[-1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

For many command line interpreters (“shell”) of Unix operating systems, the internal field separator (abbreviated IFS) refers to a variable which defines the character or characters used to separate a pattern into tokens for some operations.

IFS typically includes the space, tab, and the newline.

In your case IFS=" " [blank space],

So, by default the fields are getting separated by space.

Usage of IFS:

```
IFS=' ' read -p 'Enter your first and last name : ' first last 
echo "Hello, $first $last"
```

Sample Output:

```
Enter your first and last name : Vivek Gite
Hello, Vivek Gite
```

Please use a consistent field separator to get the results you desire.